# FETCH NOT FINISHED BLANK

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, fetch

I have a problem with `FETCH` I am using this:

```
DECLARE Something CURSOR FOR  
SELECT * FROM tblSomething

OPEN Something

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN   
        --CALL ANOTHER PROCEDURE
        FETCH NEXT FROM Something
    END 
CLOSE Something
DEALLOCATE Something
```

The problem is 10 rows are in the table and 11 rows come out, the 11th row is blank data. I think it goes to fetch the next row and realises there isnt a next row. I need some sort of:

```
IF FETCH_ROWS = MAX then STOP
```

or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `FETCH NEXT FROM` between `OPEN` and `WHILE`:

```
DECLARE Something CURSOR FOR  
SELECT * FROM tblSomething

OPEN Something
FETCH NEXT FROM Something   --  <== add this line
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN   
        --CALL ANOTHER PROCEDURE
        FETCH NEXT FROM Something
    END 
CLOSE Something
DEALLOCATE Something
```

Here is a simple demonstration with a 10 rows table and a cursor that reads each row and prints the corresponding ID:

```
declare @tmp table (row_id int)
insert into @tmp values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10) 

DECLARE @myID as int;
DECLARE @wf_Cursor as CURSOR;
SET @wf_Cursor = CURSOR FOR SELECT row_id FROM @tmp

OPEN @wf_Cursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM @wf_Cursor INTO @myID;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            print('Reading row: ' + cast(@myID as nvarchar(10)));
            FETCH NEXT FROM @wf_Cursor INTO @myID;
        END
CLOSE @wf_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE @wf_Cursor;
```

Output:

[image]